# Can not return 2D Array in Google Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am creating a Google Script to poll data from a spreadsheet (full code in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731791/getting-blank-screen-after-running-google-web-app-script)) and am getting this error when the google script is called: `Uncaught Error: The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type.` The google script is trying to return a 2D array - how can I fix the function so that it successfully passes the 2D array back to the next Javascript function?

```
function handleFormSubmit() {
    var formObject = document.getElementById('text').value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getSportData(formObject);
  }

 /**
 * Adds an html table
 */ 
 function createTable(tableData) {
  console.log("The tableData for createTable() is " + tableData);
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');

  rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });

  tableBody.appendChild(row);
});

table.appendChild(tableBody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see that your formObject variable is what you are expecting? It looks to me like it will be a single value, not an array. If you are collecting the entire form object in this way it's not a pattern I've seen before!

Comment: neither of these functions has a return statement

Comment: Try adding Logger.log to your getSportData function and make sure it is returning what you expect.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach The google.script.run call returns the output of `getSportData()` to `createTable()` - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getSportData` function return `JSON.stringify(your2Darrayvar)` instead of the actual array. 
Then in your `createTable` function use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert it back to proper 2D array.